# Оптимальная работа корзины интернет-магазина

Tags: php, javascript

Делаю корзину для интернет-магазина. Видел в некоторых CMS/плагинах для CMS реализацию с помощью cookie, но при этом всегда делался ajax-запрос на другую страницу для добавления товара.

Моя потребность заключается в том, чтобы при добавлении товара проверялась его доступность и цена, поскольку цены могут меняться по несколько раз в день для товаров. Также хочу сказать, что бэк пишется на php.

- Правильно ли будет к каждой ссылке "добавить в корзину" добавить атрибут `data-productId`, а при клике запрашивать у сервера наличие данного товара?
- Каким образом лучше добавлять товар в корзину, если это должно делаться динамически на странице (миниатюрный просмотр корзины идет по наведению на кнопку корзины)? Думал так: запрос на сервер о наличии -> если наличие есть, то добавляем в `$_COOKIE` через бэкэнд товар, клиенту отдаем `status success`, а на клиенте через js уже вставляем в список товаров нужный товар. Правильно ли это?

Comment: а что мешает при отображении товаров сразу выводить актуальные цены и кол-во? конечно на стороне php при добавлении в корзину, нудна проверка наличии кол-ва, вдруг страница долго висела, но цена хранится в одном месте и ее всегда можно получить

Answer (score 0):

1. Можете через `data-productId`, можете хоть `GET` параметром, практически без разницы.
2. А при чем здесь куки вообще? Отправляете `ajax` запрос на сервер на скрипт добавления в корзину, передавая ему `id` товара, на сервере проверяется наличие товара, если все ок, считается цена товара (условия разные могут быть) и товар кладется в корзину к пользователю, отдавая ему ответ, что все хорошо, чел, заказ принят, иначе выдаете сообщение об ошибке или отсутствии товара. Ни `JS`, ни `Cookie` здесь совершенно на при чем (в хранении заказанных товаров).

Comment: Я к тому, что данные корзины хранятся в cookie, поэтому добавляются туда таким образом) Спасибо)

Comment: @Alexxosipov в куках должен храниться идентификатор пользователя, к которому привязана корзина в БД, но не товары